# Looping through HTML elements not working with prevObject being returned

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops

I can't seem to figure this one out which is slightly embarrassing!

I am trying to loop through a few groups of elements, and then within these elements I need to be able to check whether there is another element within it (ul li ul)

```
<nav id="hamburger-nav" style="z-index: 100; opacity: 1;">
    <ul>
        <div class="cell_3 first_cel">        
            <ul class="r-list">
                <li>
                    <h1>
                        <span class="collapse resp-toogle"><i class="fa fa-caret-right fa-lg"></i></span>
                        <a class="category cars_1" href="#">Cars</a> <span>(4)</span>
                    </h1>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a class="category sub-category slow-ones" href="#">Slow ones</a> <span>(0)</span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="category sub-category fast-ones" href="#">fast ones</a> <span>(4)</span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="cell_3">        
            <ul class="r-list">
                <li>
                    <h1>
                        <a class="category trucks" href="#">Trucks</a> <span>(0)</span>
                    </h1>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

The JS is as follows:

```
$('#hamburger-nav ul div.cell_3').each(function(index) {
        if ($(this).has('ul li ul')) {
            console.log('found one');
        }
    });
```

I will get three console logs in this, and if I was to log out $(this).find('ul li ul') - I will get a prevObject, in which I don't know what this is for the second iteration of the loop.

Any help would be amazing.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's `.has()` returns a subset of elements not a boolean, you only need to change the following:

```
if ($(this).has('ul li ul'))
```

to

```
if ($(this).has('ul li ul').length)
```

[Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y8chxhxq/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#hamburger-nav ul div.cell_3').each(function(index) {
        if ($(this).has('ul li ul').length > 0) {
            console.log('found one');
            console.log($(this).has('ul li ul'))
        }
    });
```

Working **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/68rbbq2q/)**

The greater than > 0, is optional, but I put it there for readability.
The reason why you were getting a console for each list was because the $(selector).has() method returns an object regardless of whether it finds something or not. You were conditioning IF(anything), and that would pass as valid because the object showing no result is still a piece of data (i.e. prevObject, in your case). Adding length, it returns 0 if no results, and 0 is taken as false in JavaScript.

This should work for you and hope it is also clear as to why that happened :)

Comment: I have updated my answer so you understand why that happened also :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).find('ul li ul')
```

is a jQuery object, so what you're seeing output in your browser's console seems to be that object.

If you want an array of the actual DOM elements, rather than a jQuery object containing them, you can use the .get() function

```
var elementArray = $(this).find('ul li ul').get();
```